# Mount Samsung Galaxy S7 using simple-mtpfs

Tags: mount, usb-drive, android, fuse, mtp

I would like to mount my Samsung Galaxy **S7** to an folder using **simple-mtpfs** and I cannot do it as I used to (on previous Fedora and older Galaxy S4).

If I simply plug S7 to my computer, I can browse it using Nautilius, but I cannot access it in terminal as ordinary folder, what is exactly what I want to achieve.

**Every time I plug S7 I check twice that it works in MTP mode, so that isn't the problem.**

In the past, I simply plugged S4 and typed:

```
simple-mtpfs /home/adam/S4
```

Now, I can perform it and even my phone ask me to confirm MTP choice, but the catalogue S7 is still empty.

I also tried to mount it as root or ordinary user and by device number, but with no result.

```
# simple-mtpfs --list-devices
1: SamsungGalaxy models (MTP)

$ simple-mtpfs --device 1 /home/adam/S7
# simple-mtpfs --device 1 /media/s7

$ simple-mtpfs /dev/libmtp-3-1 /home/adam/s7
# simple-mtpfs /dev/libmtp-3-1 /media/s7
```

I even tried to do it by udev rules:

```
# dmesg | tail
[16821.258485] usb 3-1: Product: SAMSUNG_Android
[16821.258487] usb 3-1: Manufacturer: SAMSUNG
[16821.258489] usb 3-1: SerialNumber: 98867?????????????
[16827.556099] usb 3-1: USB disconnect, device number 29
[16830.383366] usb 3-1: new high-speed USB device number 30 using xhci_hcd
[16830.548882] usb 3-1: New USB device found, idVendor=04e8, idProduct=6860
[16830.548887] usb 3-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=4
[16830.548903] usb 3-1: Product: SAMSUNG_Android
[16830.548905] usb 3-1: Manufacturer: SAMSUNG
[16830.548907] usb 3-1: SerialNumber: 98867?????????????

# touch /etc/udev/rules.d/10-phone.rules
```

Content of */etc/udev/rules.d/10-phone.rules* is set to:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="04e8", ATTR{idProduct}="6860", SYMLINK="S7"
```

After reloading rules I have */dev/S7* and I've tried to mount it:

```
# udevadm control --reload-rules

# ls -l /dev/S7
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 15 10-20 15:03 /dev/S7 -> bus/usb/003/075

# ls -l /dev/libmtp-3-1
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 15 10-20 15:03 /dev/libmtp-3-1 -> bus/usb/003/075

# simple-mtpfs /dev/S7 /media/s7
```

**And still without any result. Mounting doesn't give and errors, but the directory where I about to mount is still empty.**

The details about my setup:

```
# uname -r
4.7.7-200.fc24.x86_64

# rpm -qa | grep mtp
simple-mtpfs-0.2-6.fc24.x86_64
libmtp-1.1.11-1.fc24.x86_64
gvfs-mtp-1.28.3-1.fc24.x86_64

# rpm -qa | grep fuse
fuse-libs-2.9.7-1.fc24.x86_64
glusterfs-fuse-3.8.4-1.fc24.x86_64
fuse-2.9.7-1.fc24.x86_64
gvfs-fuse-1.28.3-1.fc24.x86_64
```

---

**Extract from system log (Fedora's journalctl) after plugging the phone and typing *simple-mtpfs /media/s7* :**

```
# journalctl -n 53
-- Logs begin at śro 2016-10-19 21:29:20 CEST, end at sob 2016-10-22 09:26:43 CEST. --
paź 22 09:24:31 PRZEDNICZEK01 kernel: usb 3-1: USB disconnect, device number 10
paź 22 09:24:31 PRZEDNICZEK01 PackageKit[1559]: get-updates transaction /384_eccedcee from uid 1000 finished with success after 45ms
paź 22 09:24:32 PRZEDNICZEK01 kernel: usb 3-1: new high-speed USB device number 11 using xhci_hcd
paź 22 09:24:32 PRZEDNICZEK01 kernel: usb 3-1: New USB device found, idVendor=04e8, idProduct=6860
paź 22 09:24:32 PRZEDNICZEK01 kernel: usb 3-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=4
paź 22 09:24:32 PRZEDNICZEK01 kernel: usb 3-1: Product: SAMSUNG_Android
paź 22 09:24:32 PRZEDNICZEK01 kernel: usb 3-1: Manufacturer: SAMSUNG
paź 22 09:24:32 PRZEDNICZEK01 kernel: usb 3-1: SerialNumber: 98867?????????????
paź 22 09:24:32 PRZEDNICZEK01 gvfsd[1813]: PTP: reading event an error 0x02ff occurredDevice 0 (VID=04e8 and PID=6860) is a Samsung Galaxy models (MTP).
paź 22 09:24:32 PRZEDNICZEK01 gvfsd[1813]: LIBMTP ERROR: couldnt parse extension samsung.com/devicestatus:0
paź 22 09:24:32 PRZEDNICZEK01 tracker-miner-fs.desktop[2001]: (tracker-miner-fs:2001): Tracker-WARNING **: Could not find parent node for URI:'mtp://[usb:003,011]/'
paź 22 09:24:32 PRZEDNICZEK01 tracker-miner-fs.desktop[2001]: (tracker-miner-fs:2001): Tracker-WARNING **: NOTE: URI theme may be outside scheme expected, for example, expecting 'file://' when given 'http://' prefix.
paź 22 09:24:32 PRZEDNICZEK01 tracker-miner-fs.desktop[2001]: (tracker-miner-fs:2001): Tracker-WARNING **: Could not find parent node for URI:'mtp://[usb:003,011]/'
paź 22 09:24:32 PRZEDNICZEK01 tracker-miner-fs.desktop[2001]: (tracker-miner-fs:2001): Tracker-WARNING **: NOTE: URI theme may be outside scheme expected, for example, expecting 'file://' when given 'http://' prefix.
paź 22 09:24:32 PRZEDNICZEK01 tracker-miner-fs.desktop[2001]: (tracker-miner-fs:2001): Tracker-CRITICAL **: Could not set mount point in database 'urn:nepomuk:datasource:5e7b19a6b9795726a5c47a99a89757bf', GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.Tracker1.SparqlError.Internal: UNIQUE constraint 
paź 22 09:24:32 PRZEDNICZEK01 tracker-miner-fs.desktop[2001]: (tracker-miner-fs:2001): Tracker-CRITICAL **: Could not set mount point in database 'urn:nepomuk:datasource:5c7e6bb78b9a6691c3ecea3925b2971d', GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.Tracker1.SparqlError.Internal: UNIQUE constraint 
paź 22 09:24:34 PRZEDNICZEK01 org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1832]: (gnome-shell:1832): Gjs-WARNING **: JS ERROR: TypeError:  is null
paź 22 09:24:34 PRZEDNICZEK01 org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1832]: ContentTypeDiscoverer<._onContentTypeGuessed/<@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/components/autorunManager.js:133
paź 22 09:24:34 PRZEDNICZEK01 org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1832]: _proxyInvoker/asyncCallback@resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/overrides/Gio.js:86
paź 22 09:24:34 PRZEDNICZEK01 gvfsd[1813]: ** (process:3243): WARNING **: send_infos_cb: No such interface 'org.gtk.vfs.Enumerator' on object at path /org/gtk/vfs/client/enumerator/18 (g-dbus-error-quark, 19)
paź 22 09:24:34 PRZEDNICZEK01 gvfsd[1813]: ** (process:3243): WARNING **: send_infos_cb: No such interface 'org.gtk.vfs.Enumerator' on object at path /org/gtk/vfs/client/enumerator/18 (g-dbus-error-quark, 19)
paź 22 09:24:34 PRZEDNICZEK01 gvfsd[1813]: ** (process:3243): WARNING **: send_infos_cb: No such interface 'org.gtk.vfs.Enumerator' on object at path /org/gtk/vfs/client/enumerator/18 (g-dbus-error-quark, 19)
paź 22 09:24:34 PRZEDNICZEK01 gvfsd[1813]: ** (process:3243): WARNING **: send_done_cb: No such interface 'org.gtk.vfs.Enumerator' on object at path /org/gtk/vfs/client/enumerator/18 (g-dbus-error-quark, 19)
paź 22 09:24:35 PRZEDNICZEK01 PackageKit[1559]: get-updates transaction /385_decdbbba from uid 1000 finished with success after 45ms
paź 22 09:26:37 PRZEDNICZEK01 kernel: usb 3-1: usbfs: process 3385 (simple-mtpfs) did not claim interface 0 before use
paź 22 09:26:37 PRZEDNICZEK01 kernel: usb 3-1: reset high-speed USB device number 11 using xhci_hcd
paź 22 09:26:38 PRZEDNICZEK01 kernel: usb 3-1: usbfs: process 3385 (simple-mtpfs) did not claim interface 0 before use
paź 22 09:26:38 PRZEDNICZEK01 kernel: usb 3-1: usbfs: process 3250 (events) did not claim interface 0 before use
paź 22 09:26:40 PRZEDNICZEK01 kernel: usb 3-1: USB disconnect, device number 11
paź 22 09:26:40 PRZEDNICZEK01 kernel: usb 3-1: new high-speed USB device number 12 using xhci_hcd
paź 22 09:26:40 PRZEDNICZEK01 kernel: usb 3-1: New USB device found, idVendor=04e8, idProduct=6860
paź 22 09:26:40 PRZEDNICZEK01 kernel: usb 3-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=4
paź 22 09:26:40 PRZEDNICZEK01 kernel: usb 3-1: Product: SAMSUNG_Android
paź 22 09:26:40 PRZEDNICZEK01 kernel: usb 3-1: Manufacturer: SAMSUNG
paź 22 09:26:40 PRZEDNICZEK01 kernel: usb 3-1: SerialNumber: 98867?????????????
paź 22 09:26:41 PRZEDNICZEK01 gvfsd[1813]: PTP: reading event an error 0x02ff occurredDevice 0 (VID=04e8 and PID=6860) is a Samsung Galaxy models (MTP).
paź 22 09:26:41 PRZEDNICZEK01 gvfsd[1813]: LIBMTP ERROR: couldnt parse extension samsung.com/devicestatus:0
paź 22 09:26:41 PRZEDNICZEK01 tracker-miner-fs.desktop[2001]: (tracker-miner-fs:2001): Tracker-WARNING **: Could not find parent node for URI:'mtp://[usb:003,012]/'
paź 22 09:26:41 PRZEDNICZEK01 tracker-miner-fs.desktop[2001]: (tracker-miner-fs:2001): Tracker-WARNING **: NOTE: URI theme may be outside scheme expected, for example, expecting 'file://' when given 'http://' prefix.
paź 22 09:26:41 PRZEDNICZEK01 tracker-miner-fs.desktop[2001]: (tracker-miner-fs:2001): Tracker-WARNING **: Could not find parent node for URI:'mtp://[usb:003,012]/'
paź 22 09:26:41 PRZEDNICZEK01 tracker-miner-fs.desktop[2001]: (tracker-miner-fs:2001): Tracker-WARNING **: NOTE: URI theme may be outside scheme expected, for example, expecting 'file://' when given 'http://' prefix.
paź 22 09:26:41 PRZEDNICZEK01 tracker-miner-fs.desktop[2001]: (tracker-miner-fs:2001): Tracker-CRITICAL **: Could not set mount point in database 'urn:nepomuk:datasource:0e6a8582e05ac627e4014d1ca1e6ec87', GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.Tracker1.SparqlError.Internal: UNIQUE constraint 
paź 22 09:26:41 PRZEDNICZEK01 tracker-miner-fs.desktop[2001]: (tracker-miner-fs:2001): Tracker-CRITICAL **: Could not set mount point in database 'urn:nepomuk:datasource:5c7e6bb78b9a6691c3ecea3925b2971d', GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.Tracker1.SparqlError.Internal: UNIQUE constraint 
paź 22 09:26:41 PRZEDNICZEK01 dbus-daemon[1760]: [session uid=1000 pid=1760] Activating service name='org.gnome.Shell.HotplugSniffer' requested by ':1.16' (uid=1000 pid=1832 comm="/usr/bin/gnome-shell " label="unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023")
paź 22 09:26:41 PRZEDNICZEK01 dbus-daemon[1760]: [session uid=1000 pid=1760] Successfully activated service 'org.gnome.Shell.HotplugSniffer'
paź 22 09:26:42 PRZEDNICZEK01 org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1832]: (gnome-shell:1832): Gjs-WARNING **: JS ERROR: TypeError:  is null
paź 22 09:26:42 PRZEDNICZEK01 org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1832]: ContentTypeDiscoverer<._onContentTypeGuessed/<@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/components/autorunManager.js:133
paź 22 09:26:42 PRZEDNICZEK01 org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1832]: _proxyInvoker/asyncCallback@resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/overrides/Gio.js:86
paź 22 09:26:43 PRZEDNICZEK01 gvfsd[1813]: ** (process:3399): WARNING **: send_infos_cb: No such interface 'org.gtk.vfs.Enumerator' on object at path /org/gtk/vfs/client/enumerator/17 (g-dbus-error-quark, 19)
paź 22 09:26:43 PRZEDNICZEK01 gvfsd[1813]: ** (process:3399): WARNING **: send_infos_cb: No such interface 'org.gtk.vfs.Enumerator' on object at path /org/gtk/vfs/client/enumerator/17 (g-dbus-error-quark, 19)
paź 22 09:26:43 PRZEDNICZEK01 gvfsd[1813]: ** (process:3399): WARNING **: send_infos_cb: No such interface 'org.gtk.vfs.Enumerator' on object at path /org/gtk/vfs/client/enumerator/17 (g-dbus-error-quark, 19)
paź 22 09:26:43 PRZEDNICZEK01 gvfsd[1813]: ** (process:3399): WARNING **: send_done_cb: No such interface 'org.gtk.vfs.Enumerator' on object at path /org/gtk/vfs/client/enumerator/17 (g-dbus-error-quark, 19)
paź 22 09:26:43 PRZEDNICZEK01 PackageKit[1559]: get-updates transaction /386_acdeddea from uid 1000 finished with success after 48ms
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an old question, anyway, now in 2023 I can manage a Samsung phone with Android version 9 via Firefox as well as by command line (gnome-terminal) in Ubuntu Desktop 22.04.x LTS.

When the phone is connected via USB (and mounted automatically), I find the path to it using this command,

```
find /run/user/*/gvfs -maxdepth 1 -name 'mtp:*'
```

Some standard commands do not work, but then I use `gio`, for example

```
gio mount ...
gio copy ...
```

See `man gio` for details.

I made a small shellscript, than can mount, read, write and unmount the phone. It is taylored for my specific needs, but it might help you create your own shellscript, so if you wish I can copy my shellscript into this answer.

Answer (score 0):

The answer isn't straight forward, the best source of info I've found is here

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/MTP

which states that a number of newer phones are not well supported.  You may also try removing the external sd card.